# My footer element is too tall

Tags: html, css

I know what the offending element is, but I have no idea how to adjust the code to make it work. I have tried negative margins which did succeed in bringing the text up and making the box smaller, however past -150px and the text overlaps itself. Also it just isn't good practice for making a responsive website.

It's as if there is padding above the text in the .row class. But there isn't. Any suggestions?

https://jsfiddle.net/7r2wzp2m/
`enter code here`

Comment: Please consider adding your code to the question. As soon as you get a working answer and you fix you site, this question will be useless.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your `.page-footer` element, delete the `top: 340px;` attribute and instead put

```
.page-footer{
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 550px;
}
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I would restructure your HTML to have a header, main, and footer sections. More wrappers for more flexibility.

Don't put  tags in the middle of the HTML either, keep them in the header or, even better, in a separate CSS file.

Comment: So would main replace the body tag?

And for the style sections those are temporary just so I can more easily change the code. After a section is completed I move the code to a css file.

Comment: All would be inside the body. Keeping code in a CSS file shouldn't make things any harder to edit.

Comment: Reason it is is because of cache. When I update a separate file, I need to update the version number just so the browser forces a refresh. Ex: "/price-chart.css?v=0.28" I change the ?v=0.28 when I update the code from a separate file so that the browser actually picks up the new code.

Comment: If you are using chrome, while the devtools open you ca right-click the refresh icon and select 'empty cache and hard reload'. There's also an option for 'disable cache while devtools is open' under network -> disable cache. Check it out!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is from an element above it, if you add the rule

```
.container-staff::before, .container-staff::after {
    clear: both;
    display: table;
    content: ' ';
}
```

That should fix it. I agree with others though that you should restructure your html if possible, it is very hard to maintain as is right now.